# Kotlin, Android Studio, BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin and Android Studio.My problem is that My items in bottomNavigation dont appear in Emulator,there are just a background.But they are going well in `Design`.
Where I'm doing wrong? ...
Any help is much appriciated.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/whiteish"
        android:elevation="4dp"
       >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="nurbek.serzhanov"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /><!--razmer kartinki paddding-->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/whiteish"
        android:elevation="4dp"

        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home2"
        android:title=""

        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_search"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title=""
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_share"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:title="">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_likes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_likes"
        android:title=""
        >

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_profil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profil"
        android:title=""
        >

    </item>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.view.isInvisible
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        bottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item->
            when(item.itemId){
                R.id.ic_home2->{
                    true
                }
                R.id.ic_share->{
                    true

                }
                R.id.ic_search->{
                    true
                }
                R.id.ic_profil->{
                    true
                }
                R.id.ic_likes->{
                    true
                }
                else->{
                    false

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"]) 
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1' 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' 
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.2' implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: also my dependecies:

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Name to your menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home2"
        android:title="Home"

        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_search"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_share"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:title="Share">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_likes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_likes"
        android:title="Likes"
        >

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_profil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profil"
        android:title="Profile"
        >

    </item>

</menu>
```

Use `Coordinatorlayout` layout as root layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: well,i just didnt know that activty_main21.xml doesnt similar with activity_main.xml